# QT4 C++ GUI Design - Tabbed interface alternative

Tags: c++, qt4

Designing an interface with QT4 I have been advised that using multiple "Tabs" at the top of an interface to navigate different pages is not the most elegant design. Instead I would like to do something similar to the Options dialog in QT Creator 4.8.

Does anyone know the name of a widget that resembles that in the Options Dialog of QT Creator.

ex. Click Tools->Options... In QT Creator.

[image: Tabbed Interface]

Notice the layout on the left hand side of the screen, which to me seems nicer than only tabs across the top of the screen.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `QLiveView/QListWidget` with delegate that draw icon and string.

Here is link to documentation for [QListView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qlistview.html), If you are not happy with default list view delegate then you can create your own QItemDelegate to handle custom drawing. [Here](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2010/12/creating-custom-qitemdelegate-with.html) is sample code to create custom QItemDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this implementation of a ribbon interface this morning. Maybe this is helpful to you?

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4214